# jQuery .change Event Not Working With An input:text Field Which Has Readonly Set

Tags: jquery

I have written some handlers binding the jQuery .change event to the controls on my page.  One of the controls has the ReadOnly=readonly attribute set.  The .change event is not firing for just this control.

I have had a Google but can see nothing obvious.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When a control is `readyonly` there is no question of changing it or firing a `change` event.

Comment: OK sorry I should have included the detail that the field is part of an ASP .ascx control and the target, readonly, field is the text box that is updated by the calendar extender control.

Comment: This is not true, I am triggering change events on readonly fields just fine. It may help that I've also attached jQuery datepickers to them, but they are still readonly and firing change events in FF4. YMMV. Maybe an update to jQuery enabled this?